# import Javax.xml.ws.Endpoint got error

Tags: java

I use this line in my code:

```
import Javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;
```

It is error, `The import Javax cannot be resolved`. I thought that I am already using Java SE6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `javax.xml.ws.Endpoint` With 'J' in javax as small.